# Getting Calendar on main page to switch months without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I have a main page with lots of content, one piece of content is a small calendar.

For the Calendar I have a Previous month and next month link. What I want to do is switch between months without having to refresh the page.

```
<div id='cal_wrapper'>
  <a href='main.php?month=$m&year=$y' class='selector'>Previous month</a>
  <a href='main.php?month=$m&year=$y' class='selector'>Next month</a>
  <?PHP          
   echo $calendar;     
  ?>
</div>
```

Javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cal_wrapper a.selector').click(function(e){
    $('#cal_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') ); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

What is happening is when I click on either prev/next link the entire page is reloaded into the cal_wrapper div..??? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting `e.preventDefault()` first, i.e.:

```
$('#cal_wrapper a.selector').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#cal_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') ); 
});
```

Comment: To me the problem is in the $('#cal_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') ); line.  I'm haven't read up on jquery a whole lot but that seems like its loading "this" page all over again into the cal_wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, I think you want `$(this).attr('href')` to refer to the href attribute of `$('#cal_wrapper a.selector')`. Instead what is happening, is that `$(this)`, at that point, actually is referring to the `$('#cal_wrapper')` element, not the `$("#cal_wrapper a.selector')` element.

If this is correct, what you may want to do is store `$('#cal_wrapper')` in a temporary variable, i.e,

```
$('#cal_wrapper a.selector').click(function(e) {
    var o = $(this);
    $('#cal_wrapper').load($(o).attr('href')); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Tried, still same thing is happening. Thanks though.

Comment: Strange, and indeed your code should work fine. In your code, try outputting (or alerting, whatever) the value of `$(this).attr('href')` as the first line in your click handler. Is it the correct URL? It was for me when I tested it with your code in the OP.